# SP_Start_Job doesn't start on 1 of several remote servers

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

**SQL 2012**

Server `Master` starts jobs on several servers but server `Slave3` job doesn't start.  All remote jobs are owned by `SA`

`Master` job launches an SSIS package located in `Master` file system that calls SP_Start_Job in SSIS SQL Task for each remote server.  `Master` Job is owned by `boss`.  `Master` job is a scheduled task.

I can run the SSIS package in debug mode and `Slave3` job launches.  I have Sysadmin rights on all servers.  `Slave3` job does not start when `Master` Job runs on schedule.

This sounds like a permissions thing but I can't find any error or the permission required.  The `Master` job just hangs when it comes to `Slave3`.  Does anyone know what permissions are needed?  I presume the permissions are need is on `Slave3`.

The following code is in SSIS SQL Task:

```
Use msdb
go

declare @jid varchar(500)
set @jid = (select job_id from dbo.sysjobs 
where name like 'MyJob')

EXEC dbo.sp_start_job @job_id=@jid
```

Comment: What does doesn't start mean? Will *any* job start if called remotely or is it just this one?

Comment: We only call one job remotely to each Slave.   So I don't have an answer to that question.

'doesn't start' means the job on Slave 3 doesn't start.

Comment: Is anything recorded in the invoking job? What if you create a Test job on Server 3. Step of SQL and just `SELECT 1` or something else guaranteed to work. I'm curious whether it's a linked server issue or something else

Comment: and I *assume* you're kicking the remote jobs off via `EXECUTE server3.msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'MyRemoteJob'` If you're doing it a different way, would you edit the question to demonstrate how you're firing the remote jobs

Comment: Yes.  I added the code in SSIS SQL Task on Master to the question.

Comment: We do not use linked servers.  The connections are made in SSIS using OLEDB.

Comment: Remove the `go`, does it work now?

Comment: Resolved. Username running the job was missing membership in the db_datareader role to MSDB database on the remote server. After granting membership it's okay